# zend framework not working in ubuntu

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop. Happy about my accomplishment i have proceeded on to installing zend framework.

I've downloaded the files, extracted them in my `/opt directory`, made a link `/opt/zend` and included `/opt/zend/library` in my php `include_path`. I have also configured `php-cli's include_path`. I have enabled mod_rewrite.

I create my first project, i don't have `vhosts` enabled (i do not wish to create vhosts for every project), i'm fine with adding `/public` to my path.

So i have my first project created with zend tool, i test it in my browser it works. I install the Netbeans zend plugin and i create my first controller. I try to view it in my browser, says not found. That is weird.

I download my other projects made in zend, same problem. The index page is loaded but when i try to view other controllers i get a not found error. Could somebody shed some light here? I have no clue what could be the problem.

All my other zend projects are working fine on any shared hosting i use, no configuration needed whatsoever(except database).

Comment: So are you getting an error 404 from Apache or what exactly?

Comment: yes i get the 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that ubuntu's default install of apache is somehow not working with zend...unless you edit your 000-default file under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. For more details follow this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=535019&postcount=10)

Just remember to change every line Allow None to Allow All